# JavaScript choose in user cache

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script:

```
<script>
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
</script>
```

And I want the browser to remember in cache which choice the user has chosen, ex. if dark chosen always open website with dark.css

```
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('dark.css')">Dark</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('style.css')">Light</button>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Your function could store the preference in a cookie, and you could read it and use it on page load. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Never use cookies to store this kind of information! always use localStorage

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write the selection into LocalStorage as an example.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Local_storage for documentation about it. Remember to check first if it exists in the user's browser before trying to use it.

Edit, here's an example:

```
// Write to LocalStorage when clicking a button
if (window.localStorage) {
   localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
}

// Read the theme from localStorage
if (window.localStorage) {
   const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
   // do something with the theme
}
```

BUT: Can I suggest a better way than loading a different stylesheet, using CSS variables/custom properties?

Here's one example of how to achieve that: https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8

Answer (score 2):

Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Local_storage):

```js
<button id="swap-theme-btn" onclick="swapStyleSheet()">Dark</button>

<script>
function swapStyleSheet(){

    // Read and set settings in localStorage
    var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    var swappedTheme = (theme === "dark") ? "light" : "dark";
    localStorage.setItem("theme", swappedTheme);

    document
        .getElementById('pagestyle')
        .setAttribute('href', swappedTheme + ".css");

    // Change text of button
    document.querySelector('#swap-theme-btn').value = theme;
}
</script>
```